# How to configure URL Redirect in Azure DNS Zone

Tags: asp.net, azure, redirect, dns

We have multiple websites under Azure DNS Zone

> ourbusiness.net

Given multiple Web Apps like So:

> foo.ourbusiness.net
>
> bar.ourbusiness.net

We would like to add URL redirects(Correct term?) such that navigation to the following:

> foos.ourbusiness.net
>
> thafoo.ourbusiness.net
>
> morefoo.ourbusiness.net

all redirect to:

> foo.ourbusiness.net

Would need the same for other apps like bar, baz etc, not just foo.ourbusiness.net.

We do not want an alias, the browser navigation needs to navigate to foo.ourbusiness.net in the browser URL.

I think it is possible using a combination of multiple A Records and a Ptr record.  This would require a static IP or Virtual IP address(however that works.)

We use SSL.

**What is the most direct way to accomplish above requirement in Azure**?  Thx..

Comment: I recommend Azure CDN, complex rule based redirection can be easily done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your request, I think the most direct way is  to set multiple A records.

It does need a IP address for the Web App and this solution need some cost. However,

> **NOTE:** The IP address may change if you delete and recreate your web app, or change the web app mode back to free.

You can find more details about how to get an IP for Web app and  in this document: [Map an existing custom DNS name to Azure Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain)

So,if you worry about this, I  recommend you to configure CNAMEs .

Comment: I searched the document you listed for the word "IP".  As I read, it shows how to get existing IP.  Not add a static IP.  The final section "Next Steps" in [Create, change, or delete a public IP address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-public-ip-address) seems to indicate static IPs aren't for Web Apps.    Let me know if I am wrong, thx..

Comment: Hi, @ttugates . Yes, that IPs aren't for Web Apps.The way to get IP address for Web app is to create a service plan (not free). After creating it, Azure will assign the Web App an IP. If you don't delete or change the mode to free, it just like a static IP address. The NOTE is from here:https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name.md

Answer (score 0):

Based on this requirement "We do not want an alias, the browser navigation needs to navigate to foo.ourbusiness.net in the browser URL." you need a HTTP redirect to tell the browser to navigate to a different address, i.e. foo.ourbusiness.net.  That's not provided by Azure DNS but you could look at something like Azure Functions to create a HTTP reply with the correct HTTP return code etc.